# Why aren't armorers listed in credits?

Tags: credits

In productions with weapons the Armorer, a.k.a. Weapon Master, usually has a significant role -- certainly on par with other credited parties (like personal assistants, caterers, wranglers, animal handlers, etc.).  But I haven't ever found the armorer in the credits.  Why is this?

Comment: They should be. It's possible they're listed by a company rather than individual names or that they're listed under a different title than you're expecting.

Comment: I'd buy the "company" aspect, or that they may be titled under "prop-master" or some such.

Comment: I doubt the call them 'armorers'. Look under 'prop master'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An Armorer isn't listed in the credits because it's not a role/job title in the movie industry.

Weapons are props and, as such, are under the guidance of the [prop master](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_master):

> This job description varies somewhat from country to country. In the United States, food styling, **weapons** and animals are often directly or indirectly within the property master's domain.